# Initializing a (transient) EAttribute while parsing an Xtext resource

Tags: java, xtext, eclipse-emf, emf

Let's say I have a simple Xtext rule

```
Hello: "Hello" name=STRING "!";
```

but in addition to the `name` EAttribute, my (previously existing) EClass `Hello` also has an EAttribute `source` of type `EString` (or an enum type, but for now let's assume an `EString`).

This field shall not be represented in the DSL itself (hence, it is *transient* in some way). Instead, I want to have this field set to `"Xtext"` when the object was read and instantiated by the Xtext parser. (I have other ways to create instances of `Hello` for which I set other values).

Is it possible to add something to my `Hello:` rule that sets the value of `source` automatically? Or do I have to intercept the parser somewhere?

I have found some notes about "actions" in Xtext grammars and I thought, maybe something like

```
Hello: { current.source = "Xtext" } "Hello" name=STRING "!";
```

would do the trick, but it seems these kinds of actions are not allowed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way by subclassing `org.eclipse.xtext.parser.DefaultEcoreElementFactory` and Guice-Injecting it as the `org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IAstFactory` for my language.

I override create() and do

```
EObject obj = super.create(...);
if(obj instanceof Hello) 
  ((Hello)obj).setSource("Xtext");
return obj;
```

I don't know if this is the correct way, but it works.

Comment: Another Place would be the IDerivedStateComputer. Have a look at http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/18-model-optimization

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Depending on the situation, IDerivedStateComputer also seems a good place, but as far as I understand, you need to modify the MWE generation workflow. In my case, the IAstFactory was directly exchangeable by adding it to the Guice module and I was good to go, so for now I'll stick to that solution.

Comment: Nope. IDerivedStateComputer can be done via guice bindings as well